# Database Design For Restaurant Menu

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I am trying to develop an admin panel for a coffee shop.
I want to display the menu in a systematic manner.
Example For Coffee- Espresso, Latte ... so on.
Sandwiches - Northern lights , mumbai sandwich and soo on..
I want to give the admin the right to add new category say Burgers and under that the types of burgers available.
I am struggling to find the correct solution for this system.
Right now i have on table

```
Menu
CategoryId int(50),
ParentId int(50),
Name varchar(100)
```

I am able to display the menu on the front end like i want

[image: like this]

But i cannot figure out a way to make the admin add new categories without disrupting the database design

Answer (score 2):

2 tables, fk validation for ease.

```
Create table m_category (id int, 
                         cat_name varchar(30), 
                         constraint pk_catid primary key (id) );

create table m_item (id int, 
                     cat_id int, 
                     item_name varchar(30), 
                     constraint fk_catid 
                         foreign key (cat_id)
                         references m_category(id));
```

Comment: Thank You! Its Clear Now :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need two tables.

1 - Table Categories

```
CategoryId int(50),
CategoryName varchar(100)
```

This will have the following data

1 - Coffee

2 - Salads

3 - Sides

etc

2 - Table Subcategories

```
SubcategoryId int(50),
CategoryId int(50),
SubCategoryName varchar(100)
```

This will have data like this

1 - 1 - ESPRESSO

2 - 1 - AMERICANO

3 - 2 - Super Human

4 - 3 - The Green Giant

etc

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553512/join-3-tables-listing-all-records-from-ref-table/45553616#45553616).

You need two tables for this one, for subjects and another for items. You should relate every item with subject_id to its parent! Simple as it is.

Comment: Please take care to use correct case and punctuation, and avoid txtspk here. That will make your answers much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need only 1 table ,
where you can stores all data for menu and sub menu and sub sub menu ,
you need to store data in table basis of  categoryId and parentId.
CategoryId,
ParentId,
Name

All menu have 0 in parentId I.e Coffee- Espresso have 1 categoryId and Coffee- Espresso have two sub menu A,B then A,B have 1 as ParentId.